# How do I make a simple ajax call from a React page to a node server?

Tags: node.js, ajax, reactjs

I created a node project using the npx create-react-app command line. All is goo - I can display a search form on the page and I have a button that, currently, flashes up an alert just saying "Hello world".

But I want the page to make a ajax call back to the server (Currently localhost:3000) to come back with a json object.

I am used to PHP - to do this I'd just toss a PHP page on the server, make an ajax call to it using jQuery or some such thing and it'd tun the PHP script. But I can't find a way to make that same thing happen on this node server.

I thought maybe I could do a simple page that just runs this one line of code : console.log('test'); and put that in the main src directory I see, But if I try to go to it to test it, the node server that is running just sends me to the index.js code. So I put it in the public directory - it just shows the code without running it.

Where do I put js scripts to allow them to dynamically run on the Node.js server side so I can make a ajax call? Sorry if this is really basis - I am literally in only day 2 of learning node and I can't seem to find the answer to this anywhere.

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you edit your post to include your code?

Comment: I don't have any code - as is, if I were to display code it would be this :
console.log('test');

I am asking where to put it on the Node server to make it actually execute rather than just return that.

Comment: If it helps I am using the server that get's created when you do a npx create-react-app my-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to setup a basic node server

```
mkdir node-server
cd node-server
npm init
npm install express
```

then in your test.js

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

to run this

```
node test.js
```

Node doesn't follow a directory structure for pages but follows a model of routes. Routes in node represent pages as in PHP.
Now if you go to your browser and type localhost:3000 you'll see the console

Comment: I might have mis-phrased my question. What I am asking is much more basic than that.

Given that I have a file named "test.js" and it has one line in it that says "console.log('test');".... Where in the directory structure do I put that file so I can call it and view the output in a browser?

I know if I go to localhost:3000 right now there is a server running on that port that will show a page that is the default. But what is the diectory structure here so that I could go to, say, localhost:3000/test.test.js and see the js logging to the console?

Comment: Basically I just wanna know where I can put the file so that when I go to that URL I can see it execute on the server side, sort of like how I do in PHP.

Comment: That is something to be done in node world not react. You'll need to setup a basic node server and run it. I'll update my answer with the basic node setup.

Comment: AHA!!! So in other words, basically node creates a new server to act as almost a REST API - it doesn't serve it's pages from just one central server! I can kinda grasp that... totally different that I am used to but I thin I can understand it. Thanks - this is the tidbit of info that none of the tutorials ever get around to actually saying (Or at least not as well as you just explained it)!!!